# Is it feasible to use an event receiver for drag and drop? Will it scale to several hundred users?

Tags: web-part

I created an event receiver triggered on itemadded that copies to the same site and binary copies to a different site. The user can drag drop documents into specific folders and they will be both archived and sent to specific users while renamed.

Copy to different folder on same site:

```
properties.ListItem.File.CopyTo(mySavedWork.RootFolder.Name + "/" + properties.ListItem.File.Name, true);
```

Copy to subsite:

```
Stream stream = properties.ListItem.File.OpenBinaryStream();
doclibFolder.Files.Add(thisPath, stream, true); //this adds the renamed file to folder on subsite
```

The code is complete and tested.
Am I wasting my time using this method? Will it scale to several hundred users?
Do you know of a stress test other than getting a hundred users to send files?
Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

To stress test this, your best bet would be a PowerShell script adding multiple items with various Sleep intervals.

Will it scale to several hundred users? It depends. Mostly on your server's hardware resources, how SQL is setup, the solution itself, how large are the documents etc.

Personally I don't think there would be an issue, as I remember doing this for a 1000 user farm with quite low hardware resources.

Comment: Stress-testing with PowerShell will have a significant difference than in real-life: the ER would be loaded and run in the PowerShell.exe process, and not in w3wp.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if the event receiver is Asynchronous (which in this case is most probably true - as there is no point for the user to wait until a background task is finished) then it will be run under w3wp. On the other hand if it's Synchronous - it will be executed under PS process. One more way to add items is call REST services from PS - then event receivers, no matter what, will be run under w3wp.

Comment: Synchronous or not, ER are loaded and executed in the process that triggered them on the server...

Comment: I'd have to double check that. Still REST calls would be best bet - quick, easy and simple.

Comment: You were correct. Both Synchronous and Asynchronous are executed under PS process.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to consider is to know if your ER is synchronous or async. This is determined at the ER registration time: how do you register it?
In your case, asyncrhonous would be best: the copy operations would be performed on new dedicated threads (one per concurrent file), and would not block the users.

However, you stil may encouter performance problems if too many threads copy marge files: as stated by @paul-strupeikis, only stress-tests could unveil bottlenecks here, but these tests must be performed with real HTTP requests.
The first question is to determine the exact scenario: how many users (hundreds, OK)? But how many adds per user? What file size? etc.

After this, you may use the Load test templates of Visual Studio to create the scenario, and simulate users. I think we can simulate about 50-200 users from one single client machine with VS. To go further, you'd need to create a "test rig" with several VS test agents on different computers, so you can simulate a higher number of users.

For "common" scenarios and hardware, I'd bet this could be OK.

Anyway, the only other option I'm aware of would be to "log" operations to do in a queue (a technical SP list) and have a timer job do the... job!

Comment: I am grateful for all of your feedback. I had a case of the jitters to roll out what for me is a largely untested method of using SharePoint 2013 drag drop between subsites. It's a school situation so many students will send to few teachers. File size is between 20 and 200 k on average. Teachers have a folder to drop into to send back the graded assignments. Since all webs are created using LastFirst names, I tack on the student name to the document so it can get back to the right student -  no email necessary. It's too much of a burden on the teacher to do hundreds of emails a week.

Comment: 20-200k / file is not a big deal. With a correct hardware, that should go smoothly. But only a load-test would confirm this. Be sure to have async ER...  
If you have time/budget however, and if real-time copies are not required, the job is the only "safe" way to go...